# I am getting a list index out of range error

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a "Connect 4" application, but when I am running a function to see if there are four in a row I get the error: `list index out of range`.

If someone could explain to me how to fix this error but also explain why an error such as this is occurring in this part of my code, it would be greatly appreciated.

I am only including the code from the module because I think that should be enough to cover the error.

*EDIT* I am adding the code for the main method to show how the list is constructed. Also adding exact error. Thank you for all your input.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect4AlphaUpdate1.py", line 164, in 
    main()
  File "connect4AlphaUpdate1.py", line 30, in main
    winner = checkWinnerOne(boardStatus)
  File "connect4AlphaUpdate1.py", line 106, in checkWinnerOne
    if board[x][y] is 1 and board[x][y+1] is 1 and board[x][y+2] is 1 and board[x][y+3] is 1:
IndexError: list index out of range

```
def main():
# local variables
playerMove = 0
winner = False

# list to show board status
boardStatus = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
# while loop to run until there is a winner
while winner is False:
    displayBoard(boardStatus)
    playerMove = playerOneMove()
    boardStatus = checkMoveOne(boardStatus, playerMove)
    winner = checkWinnerOne(boardStatus)
    if winner is True:
        print('player one wins')
        sys.exit()
    displayBoard(boardStatus)
    playerMove = playerTwoMove()
    boardStatus = checkMoveTwo(boardStatus, playerMove)
    winner = checkWinnerTwo(boardStatus)
    if winner is True:
        print('Player 2 wins')
        sys.exit()


def checkWinnerOne(board):
# check across
for y in range(0, ROWS):
    for x in range (0, COLS -3):
        if board[x][y] is 1 and board[x+1][y] is 1 and board[x+2][y] is 1 and board[x+3][y] is 1:

            return True


# check down
for x in range (COLS):
    for y in range (ROWS -3):
        if board[x][y] is 1 and board[x][y+1] is 1 and board[x][y+2] is 1 and board[x][y+3] is 1:
            print('b')
            return True


# check diagnol 1
for x in range (COLS - 3):
    for y in range(ROWS -3):
        if board[x][y] is 1 and board[x+1][y-1] is 1 and board[x+2][y-2] is 1 and board[x+3][y-3] is 1:
            return True

# check diagnol 2
for x in range (ROWS - 3):
    for y in range(COLS -3):
        if board[x][y] is 1 and board[x+1][y+1] is 1 and board[x+2][y+2] is 1 and board[x+3][y+3] is 1:
            return True

return False
```

Comment: without seeing how `board` is constructed, and the values for `ROWS` and `COLS`, it will be difficult to help you. Also, if you could paste the exact error traceback in your question, that would be helpful. Still, generally speaking that error message is pretty self-explanatory, it means you're trying to access an index in a list that is greater than the length of the list, ex: `lst[10]` for a list with 10 elements is invalid because the indexes go from `0->9`.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to figure out exactly what is wrong, you're going to have to add a bit of information about how you're setting these lists up - this is generally the most relevant to an out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your `diagnol1` part of the function has an error. You are iterating from `0` to `ROWS-3`, however you try to access an element in the `y-1` position, which is `-1` in the first iteration when `y = 0`. Clearly, accesing the `-1` index of the list gives you the  `list index out of range` error. (same thing happens with `y-2`, `y-3`)

Solution:

That `for` loop should go from `3` to `ROWS`